# Query on Google App Maker data movement on premise

Tags: google-app-maker

I've just started exploring Google App Maker and have understood the basics. I wanted to know if there's a way by which I can push/pull data from my on premise Oracle database on to a App Maker application (model)?

As an example, if I submit a form on App Maker, I want the data to be pushed to my on premise Oracle database. Likewise, I want the Spreadsheet data to be refreshed back from my on premise Oracle database. To what I understood from my readings so far, the App Maker data can come from a Google Spreadsheet. Is there a way I can push and pull data to and from this Spreadsheet eventually to my on premise Oracle database?

Any help in this direction is much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

At this time App Maker doesn't provide out of the box connectivity to on premise databases in general and doesn't support Oracle in particular.

If you really want to use App Maker with 3rd party database, you can implement Web API that will expose it. Once you have API you can connect to from App Maker using URL Fetch. In this case you'll need to implement CRUD from the ground and it will be pretty difficult. Definitely I will not you to go down this way...